# $\limsup$ and integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limsup-and-liminf

I have functions $f$, $g$ :$(0, \infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty)$, and $g$ is invertible and decreasing (I don't know if it is relevant or not in this case). I know also that $\limsup_{x \searrow 0} \frac {g(x)} {f(x)} < \infty$. I should be able to deduce that $\int_0^r g(x) dx \leq \int_0^r f(x) dx$ for some small enough $r \in (0, 1)$. It should be easy to see, but the problem is, I don't see how.

Comment: You have twice $g$ in your integral inequality.

Comment: True, fixed it.

Comment: Did you mean for the $\limsup$ to be $<1$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. No, $<\infty$ is what was given.

Comment: Take any decreasing $g$ (which is then invertible) and let $f(x) = \dfrac 12 g(x)$. Then the $\limsup$ equals $2$ but $\int_0^r g(x) \, dx = 2 \int_0^r f(x) \, dx > \int_0^r f(x) \, dx$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thank you, I think you got me to the right track. I misunderstood the original problem, and it was actually enough that $g(x) \leq C f(x)$ where $C$ is some constant.